# function not running in window.plugins in Angular/Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, plugins, ionic-framework

**Issue:**  I'm trying to store a picture in base 64 format, but the window.plugins.Base64.encodeFile method is not running.

I've installed the Cordova Plugin locally and the $cordovaImagePicker is working correctly.  After fetching the image from the phone, it only stores the local image path in $scope.collected.selectedImage, rather than converting it to base 64 format.

Thanks for the help!!!

```
'use strict';

angular.module('copula')
  .controller('ItemsCtrl', function($scope, $state, Auth, Item, $firebaseObject, $cordovaImagePicker, $ionicPlatform) {

    var ref = new Firebase('https://copula.firebaseio.com/users');
    var authData = Auth.$getAuth();
    var itemsObject = $firebaseObject(ref.child(authData.uid + '/items'));

    itemsObject.$loaded().then(function() {
      $scope.items = itemsObject;
    });

    $scope.collection = {
      selectedImage: ''
    };
    $scope.item = {};

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

        $scope.getImageSaveContact = function() {
            // Image picker will load images according to these settings
            var options = {
                maximumImagesCount: 1, // Max number of selected images, I'm using only one for this example
                width: 800,
                height: 800,
                quality: 80            // Higher is better
            };

            $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options).then(function (results) {

                $scope.collection.selectedImage = results[0];   // We loading only one image so we can use it like this

                window.plugins.Base64.encodeFile($scope.collection.selectedImage, function(base64){  // Encode URI to Base64 needed for contacts plugin
                    console.log("before encoding");
                    $scope.collection.selectedImage = base64;
                    console.log(base64);
                });
                console.log($scope.collection.selectedImage);

            }, function(error) {
                console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));    // In case of error
            });
        };

    });

    $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function (event, viewData) {
      viewData.enableBack = true;
    });

    $scope.submitItem = function() {
      ref.child(authData.uid).child('items').push(Item.pushAttrs($scope.item));
      $scope.item = {};
      $state.go('main.home');
    };

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In all the tutorial about this Plugin they are using the result (base64) into a ng-src like this :

```
<img ng-src="{{collection.selectedImage}}">
```

Which means this plugin is returning a path, this is the normal behavior for this plugin.

```
console.log('file base64 encoding: ' + base64);
```

It is returning the path of a converted base64 img.

Your results[0] path and base64 path should be different.

Source : http://www.gajotres.net/accessing-image-galery-using-ionic-and-ngcordova/2/

Source: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-load-image-from-android-local-storage/25132/3